# identifier expected error on controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

From following controller i am getting error- identifier expected. Please have a look on the screen shot for better understanding. Picture attached

[image: pic]

Controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult _GuestNav()
        {
            using (var db = new TestWebDbEntities())
            {
                var categories = db.Categories.(x=>x.SubCategories).ToList();
                return PartialView("_GuestNav", categories); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: `var categories = db.Categories.Select(x=>x.SubCategories).ToList();` => this is you're looking for, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `Select` LINQ method can populate `Categories` data set into `IEnumerable` object you want to pass into view with `ToList()` method:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult _GuestNav()
{
    using (var db = new TestWebDbEntities())
    {
        var categories = db.Categories.Select(x => x.SubCategories).ToList();
        return PartialView("_GuestNav", categories); 
    }
}
```